# insert into data mysql database using php function

Tags: php

```
function inseartinto() 
{
    $DEL_LOG_REP = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM test WHERE itemname='111'")$DEL_LOG_REP->execute()$DEL_LOG_REP->close()return $DEL_LOG_REP
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question. That's not valid PHP for a start, and $connection isn't in the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is short tutorails on connection in insert query into php...
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

For more better understand..go to http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: i already done connection part i need to know how to write query inside the classes and functions....

Answer (score 0):

What code are you trying to writing man..
This is not a valid code for just not insert but also for connetion..
ya go onto W3School.com as mention by @Sasa.D... it provide you with knowledge from basic to expertise..